# Average length of distinct names in a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set with a `name`tsql  field

```
jimmy
jimmy
leti
joe
joe
joe
joe
```

I am trying to find the average length of unique names.  I.e for this data set the average will be 4 since the unique names are `joe, leti, jimmy` and that has an average length of 4.

I tried `SELECT avg(len(name)) FROM table GROUP BY name`

but that returns

```
5
4
3
```

and im not sure why.  How can i structure my query to get the average length of my name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery to get distinct names and then calculate average length:

```
SELECT avg(len(name)) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table) s
```